# Labels not appearing after clicking cell

Tags: ios, storyboard, label, tableview

I'm still new with programming.  I'm doing a final project for my iOS Dev class and it is to build a basic app.  I've been trying to figure out how to complete this for a few days and it's one problem after the other.  Now I am pressed for time since it is due tomorrow.  My app is supposed to show a list of chevy cars and a picture next to each car name.  This takes place in a Table View Controller.  My problem lies when I click the cell.  The labels where the information of the car are just blank.  For example, I have a label that says "horsepower," and next to it, it is supposed to display the actual horsepower of the car.  Instead of displaying the actual horsepower, it displays a blank label.  Is there anything that I am missing?  Is there a way I can show you guys the code I used?  I only have '1" reputation.

Any help would be appreciated.

This is from the tableviewcontroller:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"carTableCell";
     UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];



    cell.textLabel.text =  [_carModels objectAtIndex: indexPath.row];
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[_carImages objectAtIndex: indexPath.row]];

         return cell;
}
```

Here is my detailViewController.m

```
#import "Chevy2DetailViewController.h"

@interface Chevy2DetailViewController ()

@end

@implementation Chevy2DetailViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    _modelLabel.text = _currentCarDetail.carModel;
    _MSRPLabel.text = _currentCarDetail.carMSRP;
    _MPGLabel.text = _currentCarDetail.carMPG;
    _airbagLabel.text = _currentCarDetail.carAirbag;
    _volumeLabel.text = _currentCarDetail.carVolume;
    _horsepowerLabel.text = _currentCarDetail.carHorsepower;
    _bigImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:_currentCarDetail.thumbImageName];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Here is the TableViewController.m file:

```
//
//  Chevy2TableViewController.m
//  Chevy2
//
//  Created by Anthony Picone on 7/16/13.
//  Copyright (c) 2013 Pico. All rights reserved.
//

#import "Chevy2TableViewController.h"
#import "Chevy2TableViewCell.h"
#import "CarDetail.h"
#import "Chevy2DetailViewController.h"

@interface Chevy2TableViewController ()

@end

@implementation Chevy2TableViewController

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];




  _carModels = @[@"Spark",
             @"Sonic",
             @"Cruze",
             @"Volt",
             @"Malibu",
             @"Impala",
             @"SS",
             @"Camaro",
             @"Corvette",
             @"Equinox",
             @"Traverse",
             @"Tahoe",
             @"Suburban",
             @"Avalanche",
             @"Silverado"];

_carImages = @[@"spark.png",
               @"Sonic.png",
               @"Cruze.png",
               @"Volt.png",
               @"Malibu.png",
               @"Impala.png",
               @"SS.png",
               @"Camaro.png",
               @"corvette.png",
               @"Equinox.png",
               @"Traverse.png",
               @"Tahoe.png",
               @"Suburban.png",
               @"avalanche.png",
               @"silverado.png"];



CarDetail *sparkCarDetail = [CarDetail new];
sparkCarDetail.carModel = @"Spark";
sparkCarDetail.carMSRP = @"$12,170";
sparkCarDetail.carMPG = @"38 MPG HWY";
sparkCarDetail.carAirbag= @"10 Airbags";
sparkCarDetail.carVolume = @"31.2 Cubic Feet";
sparkCarDetail.carHorsepower = @"84 HP";
sparkCarDetail.bigImage = @"big_spark.jpg";


CarDetail *sonicCarDetail = [CarDetail new];
sonicCarDetail.carModel = @"Sonic";
sonicCarDetail.carMSRP = @"$14,185";
sonicCarDetail.carMPG = @"40 MPG HWY";
sonicCarDetail.carAirbag= @"10 Airbags";
sonicCarDetail.carVolume = @"14.9 Cubic Feet";
sonicCarDetail.carHorsepower = @"138";
sonicCarDetail.bigImage = @"big_sonic.jpg";

CarDetail *cruzeCarDetail = [CarDetail new];
cruzeCarDetail.carModel = @"Cruze";
cruzeCarDetail.carMSRP = @"$17,170";
cruzeCarDetail.carMPG = @"46 MPG HWY";
cruzeCarDetail.carAirbag = @"10 Airbags";
cruzeCarDetail.carVolume = @"15.4 Cubic Feet";
cruzeCarDetail.carHorsepower = @"138 HP";
cruzeCarDetail.bigImage = @"big_cruze.jpg";

CarDetail *voltCarDetail = [CarDetail new];
voltCarDetail.carModel = @"Volt";
voltCarDetail.carMSRP = @"$39,145";
voltCarDetail.carMPG = @"101 MPG CTY";
voltCarDetail.carAirbag = @"8 Airbags";
voltCarDetail.carVolume = @"n/a";
voltCarDetail.carHorsepower = @"149 HP";
voltCarDetail.bigImage = @"big_volt.jpg";

CarDetail *malibuCarDetail = [CarDetail new];
malibuCarDetail.carModel = @"Malibu";
malibuCarDetail.carMSRP = @"$21,995";
malibuCarDetail.carMPG = @" 37 MPG HWY";
malibuCarDetail.carAirbag = @"10 Airbags";
malibuCarDetail.carVolume = @"13.2 Cubic Feet";
malibuCarDetail.carHorsepower = @"259 HP";
malibuCarDetail.bigImage = @"big_malibu.jpg";

CarDetail *impalaCarDetail = [CarDetail new];
impalaCarDetail.carModel = @"Impala";
impalaCarDetail.carMSRP = @"$26,725";
impalaCarDetail.carMPG = @"31 MPG HWY";
impalaCarDetail.carAirbag= @"10 Airbags";
impalaCarDetail.carVolume = @"18.8 Cubic Feet";
impalaCarDetail.carHorsepower = @"305 HP";
impalaCarDetail.bigImage = @"big_impala.jpg";

CarDetail *ssCarDetail = [CarDetail new];
ssCarDetail.carModel = @"SS";
ssCarDetail.carMSRP = @"n/a";
ssCarDetail.carMPG = @"n/a";
ssCarDetail.carAirbag = @"n/a";
ssCarDetail.carVolume = @"n/a";
ssCarDetail.carHorsepower = @"415 HP";
ssCarDetail.bigImage = @"big_ss.jpg";

CarDetail *camaroCarDetail = [CarDetail new];
camaroCarDetail.carModel = @"Camaro";
camaroCarDetail.carMSRP = @"$23,345";
camaroCarDetail.carMPG = @"28 MPG HWY";
camaroCarDetail.carAirbag = @"6 Airbags";
camaroCarDetail.carVolume = @"11.3 Cubic Feet";
camaroCarDetail.carHorsepower= @"323 HP";
camaroCarDetail.bigImage = @"big_camaro.jpg";

CarDetail *corvetteCarDetail = [CarDetail new];
corvetteCarDetail.carModel = @"Corvette";
corvetteCarDetail.carMSRP = @"$49,600";
corvetteCarDetail.carMPG = @"26 MPG HWY";
corvetteCarDetail.carAirbag = @"4 Airbags";
corvetteCarDetail.carVolume = @"11.0 Cubic Feet";
corvetteCarDetail.carHorsepower = @"430 HP";
corvetteCarDetail.bigImage = @"big_corvette.jpg";

CarDetail *equinoxCarDetail = [CarDetail new];
equinoxCarDetail.carModel = @"Equinox";
equinoxCarDetail.carMSRP = @"$24,225";
equinoxCarDetail.carMPG = @"32 MPG HWY";
equinoxCarDetail.carAirbag = @"6 Airbags";
equinoxCarDetail.carVolume = @"63.7 Cubic Feet";
equinoxCarDetail.carHorsepower = @"182 HP";
equinoxCarDetail.bigImage = @"big_equinox";

CarDetail *traverseCarDetail = [CarDetail new];
traverseCarDetail.carModel = @"Traverse";
traverseCarDetail.carMSRP = @"$30,795";
traverseCarDetail.carMPG = @"24 MPG HWY";
traverseCarDetail.carAirbag = @"6 Airbags";
traverseCarDetail.carVolume = @"116.3 Cubic Feet";
traverseCarDetail.carHorsepower = @"281 HP";
traverseCarDetail.bigImage = @"big_traverse";

CarDetail *tahoeCarDetail = [CarDetail new];
tahoeCarDetail.carModel = @"Tahoe";
tahoeCarDetail.carMSRP = @"$40,405";
tahoeCarDetail.carMPG = @"21 MPG HWY";
tahoeCarDetail.carAirbag = @"6 Airbags";
tahoeCarDetail.carVolume = @"108.9 Cubic Feet";
tahoeCarDetail.carHorsepower = @"320 HP";
tahoeCarDetail.bigImage = @"big_tahoe";

CarDetail *suburbanCarDetail = [CarDetail new];
suburbanCarDetail.carModel = @"Suburban";
suburbanCarDetail.carMSRP = @"$43,870";
suburbanCarDetail.carMPG = @"21 MPG HWY";
suburbanCarDetail.carAirbag = @"6 Airbags";
suburbanCarDetail.carVolume = @"137.4";
suburbanCarDetail.carHorsepower= @"320 HP";
suburbanCarDetail.bigImage = @"big_suburban";

CarDetail *avalancheCarDetail = [CarDetail new];
avalancheCarDetail.carModel = @"Avalanche";
avalancheCarDetail.carMSRP = @"$35,980";
avalancheCarDetail.carMPG = @"21 MPG HWY";
avalancheCarDetail.carAirbag = @"6 Airbags";
avalancheCarDetail.carVolume = @"n/a";
avalancheCarDetail.carHorsepower = @"320";
avalancheCarDetail.bigImage = @"big_avalanche";

CarDetail *silveradoCarDetail = [CarDetail new];
silveradoCarDetail.carModel = @"Silverado";
silveradoCarDetail.carMSRP = @"$23,590";
silveradoCarDetail.carMPG = @"23 MPG HWY";
silveradoCarDetail.carAirbag = @"6 Airbags";
silveradoCarDetail.carVolume = @"n/a";
silveradoCarDetail.carHorsepower = @"195 HP";
silveradoCarDetail.bigImage = @"big_silverado";


_carDetails = [NSMutableArray new];



[_carDetails addObject:sparkCarDetail];

[_carDetails addObject:sonicCarDetail];

[_carDetails addObject:cruzeCarDetail];

[_carDetails addObject:voltCarDetail];

[_carDetails addObject:malibuCarDetail];

[_carDetails addObject:impalaCarDetail];

[_carDetails addObject:ssCarDetail];

[_carDetails addObject:camaroCarDetail];

[_carDetails addObject:corvetteCarDetail];

[_carDetails addObject:equinoxCarDetail];

[_carDetails addObject:traverseCarDetail];

[_carDetails addObject:tahoeCarDetail];

[_carDetails addObject:suburbanCarDetail];

[_carDetails addObject:avalancheCarDetail];

[_carDetails addObject:silveradoCarDetail];





}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}



- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView

{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}    

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [_carModels count];
}


- (UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath         *)indexPath
    {
        static NSString* kCellIdentifier = @"carTableCell";

        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:kCellIdentifier];

        if (cell == nil)
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:kCellIdentifier];

        cell.textLabel.text =  [_carModels objectAtIndex: indexPath.row];
        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[_carImages objectAtIndex: indexPath.row]];

        return cell;
    }

#pragma mark - Table view delegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Navigation logic may go here. Create and push another view controller.
    /*
     <#DetailViewController#> *detailViewController = [[<#DetailViewController#> alloc] initWithNibName:@"<#Nib name#>" bundle:nil];
     // ...
     // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
     [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
     */
}

-(void) prepareForSegue: (UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender: (id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"ShowCarDetails"])
    {
        Chevy2DetailViewController *detailViewController = [segue destinationViewController];

        NSIndexPath *myIndexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        int row = [myIndexPath row];

        detailViewController.CarDetailModel = @[_carModels[row], _carImages[row]];
    }
}

@end
```

Thanks!

Comment: Yes you could edit your question and paste your code.

Comment: Which code file should I include? The tableViewController, tableViewCell, detailviewController?

Comment: The tableViewController

Comment: Also, if you are using InterfaceBuilder(IB) check if you have connected all the outlets correctly.

Comment: add your - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath  code for reference

Comment: I'm having trouble adding the whole tableviewcontroller file because it is about 350 lines of code and stackOverflow apparently needs me to indent all of the lines of code.

Comment: If the problem lie in your other ViewController, how do you get the data from the TableView to the next ViewController? maybe that is where you are going wrong. Try some NSLogs to find where the data gets lost.

Comment: @CaptJak how would you write those NSLogs

Comment: First, I need to know how you pass the data along to the next view controller. Do you assign the variables for your labels (i.e. "horsepower") in the tableView.m file? Show me the data that you want displayed in your labels and also add into your question the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method.

Comment: @AnthonyPicone still missing the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`. Also , do the correct car pictures display when you touch their cell?

Comment: Where's your tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath method (or prepareForSegue if you using a segue to move to the detail controller)? You need to use one of those methods to pass data on to the detail controller.

Comment: @CaptJak the photo in the detailViewController doesn't show up either.

Comment: I only have the prepare for segue method, not the didSelectRowAtIndexPath   @rdelmar

Comment: That's fine, you only need one or the other. I'm not clear on your problem. Are things showing up correctly in the table view, but not in the detail controller?

Comment: @rdelmar yes, the table view is fine, stuff is missing in the detail controller

Comment: In the detail controller viewDidLoad, try logging both _modelLabel and _currentCarDetail.carModel to see if they give you what you expect.

Comment: To answer your previous question on NSLog you would do it like this `NSLOG(@"This is what my Model Label is showing %@", modelLabel);` and then the same again for currentCarDetail

Comment: Yes, that's correct (except it should be _modelLabel or self.modelLabel if that's a property).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So your problem lies in the `prepareForSegue` method that you are using. This is not actually passing the data from one viewcontroller to tn next.

In your `prepareForSegueMethod()`, try changing this:

`detailViewController.carDetailModel = @[_carModels[row], _carImages[row]];`

To this:

`detailViewController.carDetailModel = @[_carDetails[row]];`

This should just pass the array for the selected car from the `tableViewController` to the `DetailViewController`. Then in your `DetailViewController.h` file, create a property like this

`@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *carDetailModel;`

And then in the `DetailViewController.m` put in an `NSLog` like this:

`NSLog(@"contents of the array being passed over here %@", _carDetailModel)`

And see what that gives you. If you see each of the parts of the array in the Log, then you just set your labels like this, for example:

`modelLabel.text = [_carDetailModel valueforKey:@"carModel"];`

Answer (score 0):

When working with UITablViews, follow the following standard for the cellForRowAtIndexPath function:

```
- (UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString* kCellIdentifier = @"YourCellIdentifier";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:kCellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:kCellIdentifier];

    cell.textLabel.text =  [_carModels objectAtIndex: indexPath.row];
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[_carImages objectAtIndex: indexPath.row]];

    return cell;
}
```

I don't know if that saves your problem too, but worths a try.

Comment: I just tried this and I got the same result.  My cells seem fine, the problem lies when I click the cell and go to the next view controller, the labels where information is supposed to be are blank.  Thank You for your help

Comment: This is no longer the "standard" way to do this. If you use dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:, you are guaranteed to receive a cell, so there's not need to check for the cell being nil. Even using the shorter method, dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:, if you make the cell in the storyboard you will always get a cell, and your if (cell ==nil) clause will never execute.

Comment: `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` WILL return nil if there are no available cells in reuse queue and no class or nib file was registered for this identifier in this table view.

Comment: @Kreiri, not if the cell is made in the storyboard. From Apple's docs: "If the dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: method asks for a cell that’s defined in a storyboard, the method always returns a valid cell. If there is not a recycled cell waiting to be reused, the method creates a new one using the information in the storyboard itself. This eliminates the need to check the return value for nil and create a cell manually."